# Get client domain in request

Tags: node.js, post, google-cloud-platform

I have public GCP cloud function:

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  console.log(req.headers.origin);
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

and I need to get domains of clients, which will call this function. 'req.headers.origin' returns 'undefined' and 'req.headers.host' returns link of my cloud function.

Answer (score 0):

When your function is called, the `req` parameter contains the Request object from Express.  The documentation for this can be found [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.ip).  This object contains a field called `ip` which is the IP address of the caller.

We will also find the same IP address in the header `x-forwarded-for`.

We won't find the domain name (eg. xyz.com) in the data.  I think the best you will find is the callers IP address.  You may be able to perform an IP address lookup using DNS ... see the [reverse()](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/ref_dns.asp) function.